# Update state of component with componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

i have a react component that receive state from redux.

I have 3 actions { SIGNIN_REQUEST, SIGNIN_FAILURE, SIGNIN_SUCCESS }.

When the SIGNIN_FAILURE action  is called, this changes the errors status:
[image]

I have this function in my component:

```
componentWillReceiveProps( nextProps ) {
    if ( nextProps.errors != '' ) {
      this.setState({
        message: nextProps.errors,
      });
    }
  }
```

I expect that when the component receive new props, this changes the message status...but not work.

Any suggestion?

UPDATE: neither onPressLogin work as I expect.

My Component:

```
import React, {
  PropTypes,
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { Picker } from 'react-native-prefix-picker';
import Notification from 'react-native-notification';

import { signIn, signInGuest } from '../actions/SignInActions';

// other import

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  scroll: {
    paddingLeft: 16,
    paddingRight: 16,
  },
});

class SignIn extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    isConnected: PropTypes.bool,
    isWaiting: PropTypes.bool,
    errors: PropTypes.string,
    dispatch: PropTypes.func,
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      prefix: '',
      phone: '',
      password: '',
      message: '',
      errorInputT: '',
    };
    this.onPressGuest = this.onPressGuest.bind(this);
    this.onPressLogin = this.onPressLogin.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps( nextProps ) {
    if ( nextProps.errors != '' ) {
      this.setState({
        message: nextProps.errors,
      });
    }
  }

  onPressLogin() {

    if ( !this.props.isConnected ) {
      this.setState({
        message: 'Network error',
      });
      return;
    }

    const prefix = this.state.prefix;
    const phone = prefix + this.state.phone;
    const password = this.state.password;

    this.props.dispatch(signIn(phone, password));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      // ...
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    errors: state.signIn.errors,
    isWaiting: state.signIn.isWaiting,
    isConnected: state.network.isConnected,
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SignIn);
```

Notification Component:

```
import React, {
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  PropTypes,
  Text,
  Animated,
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';

const Screen = Dimensions.get('window');

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 35,
    width: Screen.width - 80,
    left: 40,
    right: 40,
    backgroundColor: '#444',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 6,
    borderRadius: 12,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    shadowRadius: 1,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 1,
    },
  },
  message: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 12,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

const propTypes = {
  fadeTime: PropTypes.number,
  minOpacity: PropTypes.number,
  maxOpacity: PropTypes.number,
  message: PropTypes.string,
};

const defaultProps = {
  fadeTime: 500,
  minOpacity: 0.0,
  maxOpacity: 0.9,
  message: '',
};

class Notification extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      opacityValue: new Animated.Value(this.props.minOpacity),
    };
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    if ( this.props.message != '' ) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    this.fadeIn();

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.fadeOut();
    }, 3000);
  }

  fadeIn = () => {
    Animated.timing(this.state.opacityValue, {
      duration: this.props.fadeTime,
      toValue: this.props.maxOpacity,
    }).start();
  }

  fadeOut = () => {
    Animated.timing(this.state.opacityValue, {
      duration: this.props.fadeTime,
      toValue: this.props.minOpacity,
    }).start();
  }

  render() {

    if ( this.props.message === '' ) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <Animated.View style={[styles.container, { opacity: this.state.opacityValue }]}>
        <Text style={styles.message}>{this.props.message}</Text>
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}

Notification.propTypes = propTypes;
Notification.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default Notification;
```

Comment: can you post the whole component?

Comment: From the code snippet you posted possible causes could be: `componentWillReceiveProps` is never called, or `nextProps.errors == ''` or new props and new state makes react think your component has not changed, causing render to run, but react not updating DOM. a  `console.log(nextProps.errors)` inside `componentWillReceiveProps()` should help you determine if any of these is the cause of your issue.

Comment: i have added console.log('LOG Message', this.state.message); inside render() and i view a new state. So the problem is the component Notification that not update with new props.

Comment: I have update question with Notification code...this is the component that receive this.state.message with <Notification message={this.state.message} />

Comment: By the title it seems to generate an infinite loop: the component is updated and when it will receive the new props it is updated again...

Comment: Component is update only if the state change, or not?

Comment: this is not the answer. but you have a bug in your code. your willRecProps function will fire all the time and every time you are going to have setStates. bad practice. you need to change the logic to this. FROM THIS `if ( nextProps.errors != '' ) {` TO THIS `if( Boolean(nextProps.errors) && (!Boolean(this.props.errors) || nextProps.errors !== this.props.errors) )` this says if we have a new error coming in and previously there wasnt one then put it in state or if the next one coming in is different than the previous error then put it in.

Comment: To address the problem you are having, What are you doing when that request comes back in your store? how are you returning the data? Also you are connecting this component but only passing one argument, make sure your null argument is the correct one

Comment: i think that the problem is here: ```shouldComponentUpdate() {
    if ( this.props.message != '' ) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: This is also not an answer, but a strategy to solve/ narrow down the issue: In your `<Notification/>` component, delete or comment out the `shouldComponentUpdate`: your component should work properly without it. Also, remove the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` stuff. Without animation, your component should render also properly. Finally, if you do the `console.log` from my previous comment (which is different from your comment), then you can further narrow down.

Answer (score 0):

In my component Notification i have delete 'shouldComponentUpdate' function.
Now the component work properly ;)